# Signing up for website payments pro in paypal sandbox redirects to live paypal site

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I have created a UK business sandbox account to test an integration of website payments pro hosted solution.  Following the intructions from paypal I go to the sandbox site (following the link from 'sandbox test accounts' page in developer.paypal.com) and log in with my sandbox username and password.  I then go to 'products and services' and click 'website payments pro' but at this point I'm redirected to the login page on the live paypal site.  Has anybody else had this problem and found a way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered that the sandbox account you created may already be Pro?  I believe all new Business accounts are Pro by default now.

That said, if you are taken to www.paypal.com/some/path, try changing it to www.sandbox.paypal.com/some/path

Comment: You're right, it turns out it is already pro.  there's no mention of it being pro by defaut in the documentation from paypal.  Thanks for your advice.