# paypal payment pro sandbox takes me to live site when trying to sign up

Tags: paypal

When I am trying to sign up for website payments pro in the sandbox, I get redirected to the live paypal site.

I have seen the same question asked here: [Signing up for website payments pro in paypal sandbox redirects to live paypal site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865032/signing-up-for-website-payments-pro-in-paypal-sandbox-redirects-to-live-paypal-s)

where the it seems that the account is already running payments pro. However on my business setup>>my payment solution it says i am running payments standard.

Any idea on how i change it to payments pro? I changed the page to sandbox.path when getting redirected but the next link redirects me again to the live site.

Thanks in advance

Nad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues that are still being addressed in the sandbox with some pages directing to the live site.  Can you provide the email address for your test sandbox seller account and I will enable pro on the account from my end.